# TSQL - ISNULL over multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a simple SQL query (SQL Server 2005) where I'm selecting from a table that contains multiple columns that have BIT values.
These columns are nullable so can contain NULL, 0 or 1.

There are a fair number of these columns and in my query I want to return zero if the value is NULL.
I'm currently using ISNULL like so:

```
SELECT Name, Age, ISNULL(LikesOranges,0), ISNULL(LikesApples,0), ISNULL(LikesPears,0)
FROM FoodPreferences
```

As I've mentioned, there are a lot of these BIT columns (much more than in the simple example above). 
Is there a way I can use ISNULL over multiple columns like this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(*,0) FROM FoodPreferences
```

The above query doesn't work but you get what I'm trying to do - so I can avoid having to write an ISNULL statement for each column,

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need the columns to be nullable?

Comment: Yes, I'm not able to modify the table in any way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> so I can avoid having to write an
>   ISNULL statement for each column,

Run this query and copy the result to your select statement. `system_type_id = 104` filters the result on `bit` columns.

```
select stuff((select  ', isnull('+name+', 0)'
              from sys.columns
              where object_id = object_id('FoodPreferences') and 
                    system_type_id = 104
              for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Result:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 isnull(LikesOranges, 0), isnull(LikesApples, 0), isnull(LikesPears, 0)
```

Comment: This is a fantastic workaround to the problem - it's this kind of creative thinking that makes SO such a valuable resource. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(LikesOranges, LikesApples, LikesPears) AS MyBit FROM FoodPreferences
```

This will return the first non-null value. If all fields are NULL the result is NULL.

---

**UPDATE:**

And the conclusion is:

```
SELECT ISNULL(COALESCE(LikesOranges, LikesApples, LikesPears),0) AS MyBit FROM FoodPreferences
```

Comment: It is not what asked. Question was to get every column data as ISNULL parameter.

Comment: yes, but it's just one step away. Let them cook the meal finally. :)

Comment: I think he means that he has many nullable columns, and want's an ISNULL on eahc column seperately (not a multicolumn coalesce) without having to actually type every column name.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so. But an option might be to create a view onto that table and put all the `ISNULL` statements in the view. At least then you won't have to do it every time

eg.

```
CREATE VIEW vwFoodPreferences
AS
SELECT Name, 
       Age, 
       ISNULL(LikesOranges,0) AS LikesOranges, 
       ISNULL(LikesApples,0) AS LikesApples, 
       ISNULL(LikesPears,0) AS LikesPears
FROM   FoodPreferences
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the simple answer is `no`.

You could write sql dynamically, but whatever happens, the final resulting sql would have to be `ISNULL(a,0), ISNULL(b,0), ISNULL(c,0), ISNULL(d,0), etc`

Answer (score 1):

i think you can write a simple program and generate select clause by reading all columns and generating the select

Answer (score -1):

while not this :

```
SELECT COALESCE(LikesOranges, LikesApples, LikesPears, 0) AS MyBit FROM FoodPreferences
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: As mentioned in the previous answers COALESCE will return the first non-null value which isn't what the question is asking.